# Socks 5 client in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, socks

I'd like to write socks 5 client using stream sockets in C.

Here is my code:

```
/*
** client_socks.c -- a stream socket socks 5 client demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "9050" // the port client will be connecting to 

#define MAXDATASIZE 100 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            perror("client: connect");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    /* Version 5, one method: no authentication */
    char buffer[256], *ptrBuff;
    ptrBuff = buffer;

    ptrBuff[0] = 5; // socks version
    ptrBuff[1] = 1;
    ptrBuff[2] = 0; // SOCKS_NOAUTH

    if (send(sockfd, ptrBuff, buffer-ptrBuff, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buffer[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("client: received '%s'\n",buffer);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

But it's not working - It's writing:

```
client: connecting to 127.0.0.1
```

and waiting, that's all

I have not found really useful examples how to do this in C, so I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

How to realize auth and no auth methods?

## New corrected code:

```
/*
** client_proxy.c -- a stream socket socks 5 client demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "9050" // the port client will be connecting to 

#define MAXDATASIZE 100 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            perror("client: connect");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    /* Version 5, one method: no authentication */
    char buffer[256], *ptrBuff, bufferf[256];
    ptrBuff = buffer;

    *(ptrBuff++) = 5; // socks version
    *(ptrBuff++) = 2;
    *(ptrBuff++) = 0x00; // no auth 
    *(ptrBuff++) = 0x02; // user pass auth

    if (send(sockfd, ptrBuff, buffer-ptrBuff, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");

    printf("sent\n");

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, bufferf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("client: received '%d'\n", bufferf[1]);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**I got:**

```
client: connecting to 127.0.0.1
sent
client: received '97
```

Every time received number is different, what's wrong?

Comment: perhaps you should be a bit more specific than "it's not working"...

Comment: indeed it's not working, otherwise you likely wouldn't be here.

Comment: It's writing client: connecting to 127.0.0.1 and waiting, that's all

Comment: Use your debugger, and more intermediate vars, eg. 'int numBytesToSend=buffer-ptrBuff;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a deeper look at this code:

```
char buffer[256], *ptrBuff;
ptrBuff = buffer;

ptrBuff[0] = 5; // socks version
ptrBuff[1] = 1;
ptrBuff[2] = 0; // SOCKS_NOAUTH

if (send(sockfd, ptrBuff, buffer-ptrBuff, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
```

You are passing to send function the `len`: `buffer-ptrBuff`. But those values (addresses) are the same address so the result is `0`.

I guess, that what you want to do is

```
char buffer[256], *ptrBuff;
ptrBuff = buffer;

*(ptrBuff++) = 5; // socks version
*(ptrBuff++) = 1;
*(ptrBuff++) = 0; // SOCKS_NOAUTH

if (send(sockfd, ptrBuff, buffer-ptrBuff, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
```

In this case `ptrBuff` value (address pointed) is incremented at each assignment so when `send` is called `len` (`buffer-ptrBuff`) will be `3`.

At the end what you are seeing is correct due to the fact that you are sending nothing to server side, and no answer can be received on client side. So `recv` waits forever (blocking mode) for an answer that will never answered.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, please, take a look at my further result

Comment: Do not edit your original question. **You have to** close this question as answered (choosing one of the answer as correct) and post another separate question with new problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
ptrBuff = buffer;
..
 //stuff that does not modify ptrBuff
..
send(sockfd, ptrBuff, buffer-ptrBuff, 0) // ie. send nothing.
```

Comment: Thanks, please, take a look at my further result

Answer (score 0):

This question is not completely answered.

According to the RFC (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1928), VER and NMETHODS are Hexadecimal values:

```
*(ptrBuff++) = 0x05; // socks version
*(ptrBuff++) = 0x02;
```

Your real mistake is that the begining of the data are pointed by buffer and the end by ptrBuff (thus, buffer-ptrBuff is a negative value).
That would be better:

```
if (send(sockfd, buffer, ptrBuff-buffer, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
```