# Socks client in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, proxy, socks

I'm trying to create socks client in C (linux). How to do this properly? Unfortunately, I have not found sufficient documentation on this issue. I've read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS, but nothing is working.

## Here is my code:

```
/*
** client_proxy.c -- a stream socket socks 5 client demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "9050" // the port client will be connecting to 

#define MAXDATASIZE 256 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            perror("client: connect");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    /* Version 5, one method: no authentication */
    char buffer[256], *ptrBuff, bufferf[256];
    ptrBuff = buffer;

    //*(ptrBuff++) = 5; // socks version
    //*(ptrBuff++) = 2;
    //*(ptrBuff++) = 0x00; // no auth 
    //*(ptrBuff++) = 0x02; // user pass auth
    //*(ptrBuff++) = '\5'; //Protocol number
    //*(ptrBuff++) = '\2'; //# of authentication methods
    //*(ptrBuff++) = '\0'; //no authentication 
    //*(ptrBuff++) = '\2'; //user+pass auth

    ptrBuff[0] = '\5'; //Protocol number
    ptrBuff[1] = '\1'; //# of authentication methods
    ptrBuff[2] = '\0'; //no authentication 
    ptrBuff[3] = '\1'; //user+pass auth

    if (send(sockfd, ptrBuff, buffer-ptrBuff, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");

    printf("sent\n");

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, bufferf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("numbytes = %d\n", numbytes);
    printf("client: received '%s'\n", bufferf);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

## A got:

```
./client_proxy 127.0.0.1
client: connecting to 127.0.0.1
sent
```

Please, help me to create socks client. Why there is no answer? How to do this correctly?

Comment: `buffer-ptrBuff == 0`, so no request is sent. Send some request to receive response. This is the same error as what is pointed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37523256/4062354).

Comment: Oh, god, really. Thanks